# Convert PNG image binary string to base64 with Javascript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm newbie on this but I have this problem, I'm using an API which gives me as result a PNG image binary string:

[image]

I want to convert this to base64 and put it as an attribute in an img tag

```
<img id="ml">
```

So tried, doing this:

```
$("#ml").attr("src",'data:image/png;base64,'+ btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(response))) );
```

But this shows me a broken image:

[image]

I tried with this getting the same error:

```
var blob = new Blob([response], {type: 'image/png'});
var reader = new FileReader();

reader.onload = function (e) {
  $('#ml').attr('src', e.target.result);
};

reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
```

Finally I used a library: https://github.com/dankogai/js-base64

```
var emk = Base64.encode(response);
$("#ml").attr("src",'data:image/png;base64,'+ emk );
```

But the result is the same.

I don't know if I'm missing something, I'd like to receive your help.

=====

**UPDATE:**

As you mentioned in the comments I mention the previous step:

I obtain this binary result from [VanceAI API](https://docs.vanceai.com/#download-result). I upload an image, then process applying an edition provided by API service and finally the result is for download, this is the code:

```
var form = new FormData();
    form.append("api_token", "XXXXXXX1234AAAAAA");
    form.append("trans_id", "XXXXBBBBVVVVVVVV"); //processed image ID

    var settings = {
      "url": "https://api-service.vanceai.com/web_api/v1/download?api_token=XXXXXXX1234AAAAAA",
      "method": "POST",
      "timeout": 0,
      "processData": false,
      "mimeType": "multipart/form-data",
      "contentType": false,
      "data": form
    };

    $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
            console.log(response); // binary result
    });
```

I also tried this:

```
$("#ml").attr("src",'data:image/png;base64,'+ btoa(response) );
```

But I get this error:

[image]

I also have to mention this result is not a Blob.

I hope you can help me.

Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246801/how-can-you-encode-a-string-to-base64-in-javascript

Comment: try this:  $("#ml").attr("src", "data:image/png;base64," + btoa(response));

Comment: By the time you read it as text the data is already broken. You need to consume the response from the server as binary data (Blob, or ArrayBuffer from an AJAX request). But maybe the easiest is to just plug your API request to the `<img>` tag, if possible. All in all, what we need to see is the request made to the API, i.e one step before.

Comment: "*binary string*" - there's your first mistake.   You either have *binary* `blob` in js terms *or* text (`string`); a string may be *encoded*.   So how you get this string is the issue - if you're using `fetch()` and `await result.text()` then change it to `await result.blob()` to get *binary*.  You can then use `FileReader` or `URL.createObjectURL`.   If you provide us with how you get the "binary string"[sic] then we might be able to help you further.

Comment: `btoa` = binary to string - so calling this on the result of `unsescape` or `encodeURIComponent` makes no sense as these return strings.

Comment: @TalmacelMarianSilviu I also tried that but it didn't work

Comment: So based on your update what you want is in `settings` you'd add a new field `{ xhrFields: { responseType: "blob" } }`, then in the `done` callback `$("#ml").prop("src", URL.createObjectURL(response))`.